# Open street map mark cluster

Tags: android, openstreetmap

I want to implement mark cluster with Open street maps, which will be displayed when zooming out.Please tell me if there is a ready-made solution for Android at the moment[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[osmbonuspack](https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack), a set of additional libraries for [osmdroid](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid), has a [Marker Clustering feature](https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack/wiki/Tutorial_3).

| Example 1 | Example 2 |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Example 1] | [image: Example 2] |